# Rails 3 RSpec and assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've thought to try to use Rspec. But I get a next problem with the assert_select.

```
1) UserController login page open login page contains all expected controls
Failure/Error: assert_select "form[action=?]", "/user/login" do MiniTest::Assertion:
Expected at least 1 element matching "form[action='/user/login']", found 0.
# (eval):2:in `assert'
# ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my code snippet

```
describe UserController do
  describe "login page open" do
    it "login page contains all expected controls" do
      get :login
      assert_select "form[action=?]", "/user/login" do
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "username"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "password"
      assert_select "input[type=?]", "submit"
    end
  end
end
```

When I open a login page in a browser this page opens without problem.

Comment: why do you have a `MiniTest::Assertion` error when you use RSpec? i guess there is something wrong in your RSpec setup!

Comment: I think too. But I did all by this [instruction](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames)

Comment: what does your `spec/spec_helper.rb` look like? did you try running your spec with the `rspec` command?

Comment: I didn't changed the spec/spec_helper.rb after it was generated. I've tried to use next several commands: `rake spec`, `rspec spec` and `bundle exec rspec spec` like in the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl.

Comment: do you have any references to minitest in your project? `grep -r "mini" .`

Comment: I've found only binary files at the `./tmp/cache/assets/`

Comment: so, then you are probably screwed :)

Comment: Sorry, I think it was a joke. :) English is not my native language. I have gem 'minitest' into the Gemfile.

Comment: "A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test
(ActionController::TestCase::Behavior)", which means you're really using minitest when calling assertions like `assert_select`. More Info: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, RSpec (at least in newer versions) prevents Rails from rendering views when you run controller specs specs. They want you to test your views in view specs, not controller specs. Since the views don't render, `assert_select` always fails.

But for people who (like me) want to test the occasional snippet of a view in their controller specs, they provide a `render_views` method. You have to call it in your `describe` or `context` block, though, not inside the `it` block.

```
describe UserController do

  render_views       # <== ADD THIS

  describe "login page open" do
    it "login page contains all expected controls" do
      get :login
      assert_select "form[action=?]", "/user/login" do
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "username"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "password"
      assert_select "input[type=?]", "submit"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller tests are for testing controllers.

`assert_select` matches something that is in your view code.

It is a good idea keep your controllers separated from your views, and this includes tests done on controllers and on views. You should use `assert_select` in your views test (the ones that are usually on `spec/views`), not on your controller tests.